# Restrict type of generic class to List of struct

Tags: c#, oop, generics

A generic interface is available that looks like this

```
interface IMatch<T>
{
    bool MatchWithExpected(T actualValue);
}
```

Implementations of this interface for different types is available already (Int, struct, Enum etc.,).

I have a struct called `ObjectType`. I want an implementation of the above interface that works with a list of `ObjectType`.

The only way I was able to do this is by doing the following

```
class MultiStructMatch<T> : IMatch<T> where T is List<ObjectType>
```

Is there any way to make `List<ObjectType>` generic that denotes `List<struct>`?
I tried `List<System.ValueType>` but cannot convert `List<ObjectType>` to `List<System.ValueType>`.

Comment: Looks like you really want is `class MultiStructMatch<T>:IMatch<List<T>> where T:struct`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass `List<T>` to `IMatch<>` and apply the type constraint to T :

```
class MultiStructMatch<T> : IMatch<List<T>> where T: struct
{
}
```

and instantiate this with :

```
struct M
{
}
...
var m = new MultiStructMatch<M>;
```

Comment: `where T : struct`, colon is missing

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a second generic parameter and declare your class like this:

```
class MultiStructMatch<T, TElement> : IMatch<T> 
    where T : List<TElement> 
    where TElement : struct
{}
```

And instantiate it e.g.:

```
var m = new MultiStructMatch<List<ObjectType>, ObjectType>();
```

<strike>This syntax is a little clumsy, because the extra type parameter seems redundant. But I don't see a better way to apply the `struct` constraint.</strike>

Obviously [Panagiotis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931138/5528593) found the better syntax.

Comment: Yeah. Syntax wise the other answer is better. But I also learnt something new, so +1 to your answer.